# c++ - winapi: Allow open external application to open only in specified rectangle

Tags: c++, winapi, monitor

Is it possible to set somehow to open external applications only in specified rectangle? I need it because I want to not to allow open for example word or something another applications to one specified extended monitor.

Next thing that I want is not to able move manually window to this extended monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The STARTUPINFO structure allows specifying window coordinates, that (IIRC) override the parameters passed when the application creates its first "overlapped" window (i.e. its main window).

However, this will definitely NOT prevent moving it.

In the precise case of Word, you may be better off using OLE to open it within your window.

Comment: but I don't open external application programatically. I want when some people is using PC, and opens manually word then I don't want to allow to open this application on extended monitor.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're SOL. Short of hooking CreateWindowEx()/MoveWindow()/SetWindowPos() etc. in all processes whenever they're created...